# What is the conservation law associated with no-cloning?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, conservation-laws

In quantum theory we have the no-cloning theorem.  It sets quantum systems apart from classical probabilistic systems where distributions can be cloned.  It implies that quantum information, in so far as it is the same as quantum states, is a conserved quantity.  Is there a conversation law and symmetry associated with no-cloning as with other conversation laws?